# httplib.ResponseNotReady when using standard Google APIs Python library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, freebase, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to run Google API Python library to use freebase API.
I followed the tutorial in this link.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started

When i run this code.

```
import freebase
query = {
 "id" :   "/en/the_beatles",
 "type" : "/music/artist",
 "album" : [{
"name" :         None,
"release_date" : None,
"track": {
    "return" : "count"
},
"sort" : "release_date"
}]
}
freebase.mqlread(query)
```

I got this error

httplib.ResponseNotReady

Anybody could help me resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in google-api-python-client library that would support "import freebase". It looks like you are using the deprecated freebase library at https://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/.

I would suggest starting with the skeleton application you get by creating using the [Quickstart for Freebase](https://developers.google.com/quickstart/), and then add the following Python code to make the query:

```
import json

query = {
  "id" :   "/en/the_beatles",
  "type" : "/music/artist",
  "album" : [{
    "name" :         None,
    "release_date" : None,
    "sort" : "release_date",
  }]
}    

pprint.pprint(service.mqlread(query=json.dumps(query)).execute())
```